# ASPxGridview - Enable a specific columns "AllowHeaderFilter" property to true code behind?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm very frustrated as I can't seem to figure out how to turn on allowheaderfilter property to true for a specific column. It appears that I can only do this in design view. I must be able to do it code behind as I have certain conditions when this can be done.

Is this possibe?

Thanks,

Timothy

Answer (score 0):

We have answered a similar question at:

[Enable Column Header Filter Code Behind](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q305246)